# Deploy error on JBOSS 7 eap , @EJB issue with deploy in a bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, cdi

Good day

I am trying to deploy an existing application to JBOSS EAP 7, But the deploy failed with following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0033: interface javax.ejb.EJB annotation not found on InterfaceTest  ClassA \"}}"
at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldEjbInjectionServices.registerEjbInjectionPoint(WeldEjbInjectionServices.java:97)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$EjbResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:274)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$EjbResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:269)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createFieldResourceInjection(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:217)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:189)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.discoverType(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:449)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.getResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:97)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:59)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.of(ResourceInjector.java:49)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.createDefault(BeanInjectionTarget.java:47)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:113)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:100)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:80)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:261)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:228)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:78)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:75)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

where **ClassA** is

```
   @Named(value = "ao007")
   @ViewAccessScoped
   public class classA {

     @EJB
     InterfacTest test;

   }
```

**InterfaceTest** is

```
   @Remote
   public interface InterfaceTest {

   }
```

**EJB** is

```
   @Stateless
   @Interceptors(Interceptor.class)
   public class EJBTest implements InterfaceTest {

   }
```

Every `.class` is in the same jar , the jar is in the `web-inf lib` of the war which I am deploying

I searched a lot but seems nobody have had this errors

Thanks in advance

Comment: One line from you stack trace is not very useful. Please provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: classA is a managedbean, with @  injject deploy works but why not with @ejb,

Comment: Does the jar containing the classes include a `beans.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the InterfaceTest you don't need to put the @Remote twice (on EJBTest and InterfaceTest), put only on InterfaceTest.

Did you try the injection with @Inject?

What's the context of classA? Don't you have to put @Named on it?

Comment: yes i have forgotten to add @named to the code above

Answer (score 0):

`ClassA` is not a "managed component", eg. EJB. Therefore injection into it can not be performed.

Comment: No the classA is a managedBeam , in Weblogic 12c the codes deploy and works fine ,also the @EJB injectcion